# Multidimensional array with enum type and casting them into unsigned char array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, casting, enums

here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3
#define COPY(a, i) (a[(i)]) = (a[((i)+1)])

enum course {BTP300 = 1, OOP244, OOP344, OOP444, BTP400 = 8, BTP500};
typedef enum course Course;

void display(void* a, int n) {
    int i;
    unsigned char* c = (unsigned char*)a;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", c[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void process(void *c, int n, int s) {
    int i, j;
    unsigned char* a = (unsigned char*)c;

    for (i = 0; i < s * n; i++) {
        unsigned char x = a[i];
        for (j = 1; j < s - 1; j++, i++)
            COPY(a, i);
        a[++i] = x;
    }
}

int main() {
    Course array[2][N] = {BTP300, BTP400, BTP500, OOP244, OOP344, OOP444};

    display(array[1], sizeof(Course)*N);
    display(array[0], sizeof(Course)*N);
    process(array[0], N, sizeof(Course));
    process(array[1], N, sizeof(Course));
    display(array[1], sizeof(Course)*N);
    display(array[0], sizeof(Course)*N);
    return 0;
}
```

## The out put is:

```
2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 9 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 4
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 9
```

now what it seems like when casting the pointer the size comes into play. I initially thought that though memory is created, in arrays you just jump over. so i would still get 234. but no. I get 1byte char.

```
0 2
1 0
2 0
3 0
```

And this gets printed too.

whats going on?

Comment: As there's no C++ in the provided code, I changed the tag to C.

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration values are of type `int` in C, and `int` is commonly four bytes (32 bits) on most platforms. So trying to access the values as `char` will not give you the expected result.

For the `display` function you do not need to multiply with `sizeof(Course)`, the number of entries is `N` so that is the size you should provide to the function:

```
display(array[1], N);
```

And of course you should be using either `int` for the separate values, or `Course`.

And you need to rethink your `process` function as well.